# MySQL - Which is better: SELECT or SELECT COUNT?

Tags: mysql

Let's suppose I have a field in a table I want to check, and said field has the value "on" stored in it. Now, which of these is recommendable?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM table WHERE field='on'
if (c > 0) { //execute script }
```

or

```
SELECT field FROM table
if (field == 'on') { //execute script }
```

Comment: Why not: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE field='on' having COUNT(*) >0
 { //execute script }`

Comment: The 2 queries yield totally different outputs, how do you want to compare them?

Comment: I want to compare which is faster and will do better in a heavy environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM table WHERE field='on'
if (c > 0) { //execute script }
```

First one is faster because query itself count the record and fetch the desire records only with where field='on' condition. So it is taking less time to execute such query also take less memory. 
One of the most useful benefit is speed up.

```
SELECT field FROM table
if (field == 'on') { //execute script }
```

Second action taking time when using large database because its fetch all the records from database and then we are checking filed=='on' condition.

So first one is better to implement.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First one is better or fast way

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM table WHERE field='on'
```

because `if (c > 0)` is more faster than `if (field == 'on')`

Comment: Isn't `count(*)` slower than `count(field)`?